# How to split conditionally in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like this

`"Earth Continuity (4;1) due to;Electric safety devices(4;2) due to;Electric safety devices(4;2) Top Final Limit Switch"`

and I need to split this string and the output should look like Bello

```
[Earth Continuity (4;1) due to,Electric safety devices(4;2) due to,
Electric safety devices(4;2) Top Final Limit Switch]
```

here the delimiter is `;` but if a digit comes before and after the delimiter for example `(4;5)`, I need to skip the splitting hence I can't split using `;` instead I need Regexp to do this.

can anyone help me out to solve this problem?

Comment: Use: `myString.split(/(?<=\D);(?=\D)/)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass a regex rather than a string to the `split` function:

```js
var str = "Earth Continuity (4;1) due to;Electric safety devices(4;2) due to;Electric safety devices(4;2) Top Final Limit Switch";
var splitStr = str.split(/(?<!\d);(?!\d)/)

console.log(splitStr);
```

Explanation:

- `(?<!)` signifies a negative lookbehind
- `\d` in `(?<!\d)` represents a number (0-9)
- `;` literally matches a semicolon `;`
- `(?!)` is a negative lookahead

Comment: Or with positive lookbehind/ahead: `/(?<=\D);(?=\D)/`

Comment: str.split(/(?<!\d);(?!\d)/) - this works fine in Chrome, but having issue in IE..do u have any other alternative? issue with ?<!